# Override standard function which is friend of class

Tags: c++

There is such class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Element {
private:
  int val;
public:
  Element(int val_){ val = val_;}
  friend Element std::pow(Element a, int exp);
};
```

I'd like to override standard function pow, which is friend of class Element, to work with objects of my class. However, there is following error during compilation:

```
error: ‘Element std::pow(Element, int)’ should have been declared inside ‘std’
```

How to override standard pow function?

Comment: Why do you want to override the function from std and not use "standalone" function named similary in another namespace?

Comment: I'd like to write some mathematical function which accepts arguments of standard data types and my own data type, and uses power function.

Comment: Then make that mathematical function templated on types and partially specialize it on your own classes to use your function (note I'm not native English speaker and I'm not sure if "partially specialize" is right expression here, correct me if I'm mistaken).

Comment: @Grives, your English is correct I think :D, but the explanation is not. `std::pow` and the family are not templates, and you don't need templates here, overloading is sufficient.

Comment: @Kos, I was not reffering to std::pow, but to "some mathematical function", which OP was reffering to and make that "some mathematical function" a templated and partially specialized one. But of course the easiest (and accepted ATM) answer is the best ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't `override`, you `overload`. The term `override` relates to virtual functions, and `overload` to choosing the right function basing on parameter types.

The solution is simple: **don't write `std::pow`, just write a `pow`.** Or `yournamespace::pow`, if you prefer - doesn't matter. Yes, it's just that.

Then:

```
double a;
Element b;

using std::pow;
pow(a, 10.0);    // calls std::pow(double, double)
pow(Element, 10) // calls pow(Element, int)
```

Explanation: In C++ there's a wild thing called ADL (or Koenig's lookup) which will basically decide which variant to use, and it will choose the overload from any namespace without you needing to specify it at the place of the call.

Have a read:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do this.  For one thing, you are not allowed to put user-defined things inside the `std` namespace.

You will need to write your own `pow` function, that is not inside `std`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for as start you shouldn't be adding things to namespace `std`.

Your `pow` overload should be in a separate namespace. You should then be

```
using std::pow
using my::pow;
```

Debatable style point that I endorse: generic functions like this should not be namespace-qualified. That is to say, use the `using` and call `pow()` in client code instead of `std::pow()`, same applies to `std::swap` and other customisation points.

The only time you can extend the `std` namespace is with template specialisations. Again, consider `std::swap`.

Comment: Is it a good practice to specialise std::swap (as opposed to overloading it)?

Comment: It's the only way permitted by the standard.

Comment: @Kos: You can provide a different `swap` function that will be picked up by ADL and that way you don't need to specialize/overload it. The idiom for calling `swap` should be, as this answer points out: `void foo( Type x, Type y ) { using std::swap; swap( x.a, y.a ); }` That way it will lookup `swap` in both `std` or the namespace where the type of `Type::a` is defined.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the function in the standard namespace, or else it does not exist:

```
namespace std {
    Element pow(Element a, int exp) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, polluting std namespace is not the solution. For solution see Oli's answer.

Comment: You are forbidden from doing that by the standard.